# Read dropdown list value clicked without submit

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can I fulfill my scope? I want to have on my webpage a drop-down list with some  static option after I am clicking on an item from the dropdown list (language)

```
<td align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <SELECT name="language"  >
        <OPTION value="ro" selected>Romana</OPTION>
        <option value="en">English</option>
        <option value="de">Deutsch</option>
    </SELECT>
```

selecting one the options I want that the `$language` variable to get the new 
value and reload the page with the `$language` variable changed.
On the targeted web pages I got a PHP function what is returning the HTML text elements base on the `$language` variable value (this part is already working).
The following is my complete setup:
`index.php`

```
<?php

if( isset( $_GET['target'] ) )
    $target = $_GET['target'];
else
    $target = "productie";

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Frameset//EN">
<!-- saved from url=English/index.php -->
<HTML><HEAD><META content="IE=7.0000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<TITLE>website name</TITLE><!-- 

-->

</HEAD>
<FRAMESET frameSpacing=0 border=0 frameBorder=NO rows=65,* cols=*>
<FRAME noResize marginHeight=0 src="web_files/top.html" name=topFrame marginWidth=0 scrolling=no>
<FRAMESET frameSpacing=0 border=0 frameBorder=NO cols=224,*>
<FRAME noResize marginHeight=0 src="web_files/menu.php?target=<?php echo $target?>" name=leftFrame marginWidth=0>
<FRAME marginHeight=0 src="web_files/right.php?target=<?php 
    echo $target; 
    if( isset( $_GET['id'] ) ) 
    ?>" name="contentFrame" id="content" marginWidth=0>
</FRAMESET>
</FRAMESET>
</HTML>
```

the next one is the `menu.php` i was thinking to put in here the option list

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<!-- saved from url=(0099)http://w01abin05/intranet/english/navigation/Control.php -->
<HTML><HEAD><META content="IE=5.0000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<TITLE>TAKATA</TITLE><!-- 
 -->
<LINK rel=stylesheet 
type=text/css href="Control_files/style_header.css">
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript type=text/JavaScript 
src="Control_files/script.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript type=text/JavaScript>
var i = "leer";
function highlight (id)
{
    if(i!='leer')
    document.getElementById(i).style.color="#ffffff";   

    document.getElementById(id).style.color="#000000";
    i=id;
}

function changeOver(id)
{
   if(id!=i)
    document.getElementById(id).style.color="#000000";      
}

function changeOut(id)
{              
    if(id!=i)
        document.getElementById(id).style.color="#ffffff";      
}
</SCRIPT>

<META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 10.00.9200.17028"></HEAD>
<BODY background="Control_files/bg_navi2.jpg" leftMargin=0 topMargin=0 marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
<TABLE height="96%" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width=208 border=0>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD class=blue12bold vAlign=top background="Control_files/bg_navi.gif"  height="5%"><BR />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Rapoarte OPFSYS</TD></TR>
  <TR >
    <TD vAlign=top height="2%" valign="top" <?php if( $_GET['target'] == 'productie' ) echo " bgcolor=\"#A0A0A0\" ";?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../index.php?target=productie" target="_parent">Raport productie</a></TD></TR>
  <TR >
    <TD vAlign=top height="2%" valign="top" <?php if( $_GET['target'] == 'productie_celule' ) echo " bgcolor=\"#A0A0A0\" ";?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../index.php?target=productie_celule" target="_parent">Productie celule</a></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD vAlign=top height="2%" <?php if( $_GET['target'] == 'id_details' ) echo " bgcolor=\"#A0A0A0\" ";?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../index.php?target=id_details" target="_parent">Trasabilitate piesa</a></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD vAlign=top height="2%" <?php if( $_GET['target'] == 'pontaj' ) echo " bgcolor=\"#A0A0A0\" ";?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../index.php?target=pontaj" target="_parent">Pontaj celule</a></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD vAlign=top height="2%" <?php if( $_GET['target'] == 'wip' ) echo " bgcolor=\"#A0A0A0\" ";?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../index.php?target=wip" target="_parent">Piese in lucru</a></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD vAlign=top height="2%" <?php if( $_GET['target'] == 'rework' ) echo " bgcolor=\"#A0A0A0\" ";?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../index.php?target=rework" target="_parent">Reparatii</a></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD vAlign=top height="2%" <?php if( $_GET['target'] == 'logistics' ) echo " bgcolor=\"#A0A0A0\" ";?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../index.php?target=logistics" target="_parent">Raport logistica</a></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD vAlign=top height="2%" <?php if( $_GET['target'] == 'perf_celule' ) echo " bgcolor=\"#A0A0A0\" ";?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../index.php?target=perf_celule" target="_parent">Performanta celule</a></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD vAlign=top height="2%" <?php if( $_GET['target'] == 'downtime' ) echo " bgcolor=\"#A0A0A0\" ";?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../index.php?target=downtime" target="_parent">Raport intreruperi</a></TD></TR>
<!--
  <TR>
    <TD vAlign=top height="2%" <?php if( $_GET['target'] == 'new_report' ) echo " bgcolor=\"#A0A0A0\" ";?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../index.php?target=new_report" target="_parent">Raport nou</a></TD></TR>
!-->
<TR>
    <TD vAlign=top height="2%" <?php if( $_GET['target'] == 'first_time' ) echo " bgcolor=\"#A0A0A0\" ";?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../index.php?target=first_time" target="_parent">First Time Pass</a></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD vAlign=top height="2%" <?php if( $_GET['target'] == 'qgate' ) echo " bgcolor=\"#A0A0A0\" ";?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../index.php?target=qgate" target="_parent">Raport Q-gate</a></TD></TR>

  <TR>
    <TD vAlign=top height="2%">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/OPFSYS/web/" target="_blank">Ajustare performanta</a></TD></TR>
     <TR>
    <TD vAlign=top height="2%">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://server1/portal" target="_blank">Helpdesk PE-IT</a></TD></TR>

  <!--
  <TR>
    <TD vAlign=top height="2%">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../index.php?target=combined" target="_parent">Raport combinat</a></TD></TR>
  !-->
  <tr>
    <TD class=blue12bold vAlign=top background="Control_files/bg_navi.gif"  height="5%"><BR />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Rapoarte Montaj</TD></TR>
  <TR>
  <TR>
    <TD vAlign=top height="2%" <?php if( $_GET['target'] == 'bmw_ms_fa_control' ) echo " bgcolor=\"#A0A0A0\" ";?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../index.php?target=bmw_ms_fa_control" target="_parent">Control BMW MS</a></TD></TR>
    <TR><TD vAlign=top height="2%" <?php if( $_GET['target'] == 'bmw_ukl_opc' ) echo " bgcolor=\"#A0A0A0\" ";?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../index.php?target=bmw_ukl_opc" target="_parent">Log OPC BMW UKL</a></TD></TR>
    <TR><TD vAlign=top height="2%" <?php if( $_GET['target'] == 'labelling' ) echo " bgcolor=\"#A0A0A0\" ";?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../index.php?target=labelling" target="_parent">Reetichetare</a></TD></TR>
    <tr>
    <TD class=blue12bold vAlign=top background="Control_files/bg_navi.gif"  height="5%"><BR />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Rapoarte Turnatorie</TD></TR>
  <TR>
  <TR>
    <TD vAlign=top height="2%"<?php if( $_GET['target'] == 'dc_dot_marking' ) echo " bgcolor=\"#A0A0A0\" ";?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../index.php?target=dc_dot_marking" target="_parent"><img src="Control_files/circle_big.png" style="width:5px;height:5px;" alt="dot" border="0"> marking</a></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD vAlign=bottom align=left  ><IMG src="Control_files/nav_logo.gif" 
      width=47 height=211>
    </TD>
</TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>

</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: Yes, please share the rest of your code so we can help you out.
And please explain more, do you want no submitting or no refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of the newly selected option by using the [`onchange`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select[name=language]').change(function() {

  });
});
```

If you want to submit data, add an [`ajax post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select[name=language]').change(function() {
       var _lang = $( "select['name=language'] option:selected" ).text(); //Get the text of the selected option, you can use .val() instead to get the the content of the value attribute
       $.post( "languageHandler.php",{ language: _lang}, function(data) {
             $('body').append(data); //Append the new data to body
        });

  });
});
```

Comment: i would use `.val()` and not `.text()`

Comment: Both will work, it just depends on how you handle it in the PHP, so if `.val()` is what you want to handle, just replace the `.text()` by `.val()`.
If you find my solution helpful, please mark it as the solution to your question.

Comment: It's not my question!

Comment: Ah thanks, sorry i thought you are the question asker haha, my baad